# openGL gl_Polygon mix color issue

Tags: c++, opengl

I want to draw two rectangle one on left and one on right with 2 different colors, but after I draw with two `GL_Polygon`. the image turn out to be this, can anyone help me out?
Thank You.

```
{
    GLfloat rectangleB[5][3]={{10,0,0},{10,30,0},{5,30,0},{1,30,0},{1,0,0}};
    GLfloat rectangleW[5][3]={{0,0,0},{0,30,0},{-5,30,0},{-10,30,0},{-10,0,0}};
    GLfloat rectangleY[5][3]={{8,2,0},{5,28,0},{0,28,0},{-8,28,0},{-8,2,0}};

    void draw_Rectangle(void){

    glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
    for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
        glVertex3fv(rectangleB[i]);
        glColor3f(0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
    }
    glEnd();

    glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
    for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
        glVertex3fv(rectangleW[i]);
        glColor3f(1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
    }
    glEnd();


    glFlush();
}
```

this is output image

[image]

this is the image I want

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all note, that drawing by `glBegin`/`glEnd` sequences is deprecated since several years.
Read about [Fixed Function Pipeline](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Fixed_Function_Pipeline) and see [Vertex Specification](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Vertex_Specification) and [Shader](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Shader) for a state of the art way of rendering.

---

Anyway, [`glVertex`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glVertex.xml) is used to specifies the next vertex coordinate within a [`glBegin`/`glEnd`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glBegin.xml) sequence.
When `glVertex` is called, then the current color attribute ([`glColor`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glColor.xml)) is associated with the vertex coordinate.

This means you have to set the color **before** you specify the vertex coordinate. Swap `glColor3f` and `glVertex3fv` to solve your issue:

```
glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
    glColor3f(0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
    glVertex3fv(rectangleB[i]);
}
glEnd();

glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
    glColor3f(1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
    glVertex3fv(rectangleW[i]);
}
glEnd();
```

Comment: [link]Thank you.[link]